# Removing Counter from date Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am fairly new to Python and have a small problem.

I have some code which takes a date and returns a series of forward looking business days. All good so far.  The only problem is that in the output I have what looks like a count associated with each date so for example I have this:

```
0    2001-01-01
1    2001-01-02
2    2001-01-03
3    2001-01-04
4    2001-01-05
5    2001-01-08
6    2001-01-09
7    2001-01-10
8    2001-01-11
9    2001-01-12
10   2001-01-15
```

when I would actually like to see:

```
2001-01-01
2001-01-02
2001-01-03
2001-01-04
2001-01-05
2001-01-08
2001-01-09
2001-01-10
2001-01-11
2001-01-12
2001-01-15
```

My code is below:

```
    def getBusinessDayCalender(startDate,insampleLength,outsampleLength):

        print('getBusinessDayCalender')

        from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
        weekmask_europe = 'Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri'

        bday_europe = CustomBusinessDay(weekmask=weekmask_europe)

        dt = pd.datetime(startDate.year, startDate.month, startDate.day)

        dts = pd.date_range(dt, periods=insampleLength+outsampleLength, freq=bday_europe)

        dates = pd.Series(dts)
        print(dates)
        return dates
```

Comment: Could you try to show the type of your variable ? Is the first one a Pandas Series ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the hack. However it would work well.

```
>>> data_list
'0    2001-01-01\n1    2001-01-02\n2    2001-01-03\n3    2001-01-04\n4    2001-01-05\n5    2001-01-08\n6    2001-01-09\n7    2001-01-10\n8    2001-01-11\n9    2001-01-12\n10   2001-01-15'
>>> [data[data.index('-') - 4:] for data in data_list.split('\n')]
['2001-01-01', '2001-01-02', '2001-01-03', '2001-01-04', '2001-01-05', '2001-01-08', '2001-01-09', '2001-01-10', '2001-01-11', '2001-01-12', '2001-01-15']
```

Answer (score 0):

All Series (and DataFrames) are indexed in Pandas, see the [docs.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html)

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series([0,3,1])
        s
Out[2]: 0    0
        1    3
        2    1
        dtype: int64

In [3]: s[1]
Out[3]: 3
```

Your **real data** is in the *second column*.